# Integrating Diff Tools With Visual Studio 2003

Tags: diff, visual-studio-2003

I found a great article on integrating different diff and merge tools with Visual Studio 2005 and 2008: http://blogs.msdn.com/jmanning/articles/535573.aspx.

Does anyone know how I might integrate a tool like KDiff3 in the same way with Visual Studio.Net 2003? I would like to have KDiff3 be the default diff tool when I use the "Compare Versions..." menu item in the Solution Explorer.

For our source control, we're using Team System 2005, using the msscci provider to integrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for that question and comment. It got me to realize the compare was coming from VS2005, even though I'm using VS2003, because the msscci provider I'm using for source control integration is the VS2005 version.

So, by going into VS2005 and using "Configure User Tools...", it forces 2003 to use the same tools.

Comment: No Problem.  I've never used Team System 2005, so I would never have gotten there...

Answer (score 1):

What source control system are you using?

With certain systems you can specify what diff tool you'd like to use.  Perforce has this...and I believe VisualSVN lets you choose what diff tool as well.

If you've got VSS...I think you're out of luck...

Comment: I'm using Team System 2005 with an msscci provider to integrate the two.

Answer (score 0):

I know that [Devart CodeCompare](http://www.devart.com/codecompare/) shows good results on the integration with Visual Studio. But I don't know what VS versions are compatible with CodeCompare.